# Memory fault(coredump) during Icinga (1.x) startup

Tags: nagios, icinga

I am getting this error in the Icinga startup -

```
/pkgs/icinga/1.13.3.rhas5/bin/icinga  /my-config/dit-icinga-app-master/config/icinga.cfg

Icinga 1.13.3
Copyright (c) 2009-2015 Icinga Development Team (http://www.icinga.org)
Copyright (c) 2009-2013 Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 07-15-2015
License: GPL

Icinga 1.13.3 starting... (PID=30807)
Local time is Fri Feb 05 16:45:17 EST 2016
idomod: IDOMOD 1.13.3 (07-15-2015) Copyright(c) 2005-2008 Ethan Galstad, Copyright(c) 2009-2015 Icinga Development Team (https://www.icinga.org)
idomod: Successfully connected to data sink.  0 queued items to flush.
Memory fault(coredump)
```

Log file does not reveal much
icinga.log

```
[1454708717] Icinga 1.13.3 starting... (PID=30807)
[1454708717] Local time is Fri Feb 05 16:45:17 EST 2016
[1454708717] LOG VERSION: 2.0
[1454708717] idomod: IDOMOD 1.13.3 (07-15-2015) Copyright(c) 2005-2008 Ethan Galstad, Copyright(c) 2009-2015 Icinga Development Team (https://www.icinga.org)
[1454708717] idomod: Successfully connected to data sink.  0 queued items to flush.
[1454708717] Event broker module 'IDOMOD' version '1.13.3' from '/pkgs/icinga_idoutils_libdbi_mysql/1.13.3/lib64/icinga/idomod.so' initialized successfully.
[1454708718] Event loop started...
icinga.log (END)
```

Icinga pre-flight check looks OK, so there is no issue with any of the configuration files.

Also, MySQL database is running on the node and I do see some data being inserted to it also in ido2db.debug logs.

Wondering where can I get more logs? Anybody has any leads? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't know about your specific situation, but "Memory fault" is either caused by hardware error (extremely rare, but more common since hardware did get bigger and less robust), or software error on the level of machine code. This later could either be a result of errors in the program, or as well in the compiler. --- If you can reliably reproduce the error, then it is not an error with your chips.